# feign.FeignException: status 401 error when REST API using a feign client tries to connect

Tags: java, rest, spring-cloud-feign

I have a Spring Boot REST API written in Java.  I am using a Feign client to connect to another REST API.  The endpoint uses to header parameters, apikey and serviceName.
I get this error when the endpoint calls the feign client.

```
feign.FeignException: status 401 reading FacilityViewClient#getFacilities(Map,String,String)\r\n\tat feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:78)
```

This is how I have implemented the feign client with header parameters:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/schedule-svc/api/v1/facilities")
    FacilitiesViewResponse getFacilities(@RequestHeader Map headers,
                                         @RequestParam("facilityType") String facilityType,
                                         @RequestParam("stateProvinceCode") String stateProvinceCode);
```

This is the call using the feign client:

```
Map<String, Object> headerMap = new HashMap<>();
 headerMap.put("apikey", "xxxxxxx" );
 headerMap.put("SERVICE-NAME", "Location");

 FacilitiesViewResponse facilitiesViewResponse = facilityViewClient.getFacilities( headerMap,"RALYD", "PA");
```

I have also tried to use individual @RequestHeader string parameters and get the same error.  Like this:

```
@RequestHeader("apikey") String apiKey
@RequestHeader("SERVICE-NAME") String serviceName
```

The same error occurs.

I can hit the service using Postman and the header information looks like this:
[image]

Are there other properties that need to be defined in the feign client to successfully set the header parameters

Answer (score 1):

we solved this problem. The url and path were wrong on the FeignClient.  The error was misleading us to think it was an unauthorized error when actually it was a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your feign client configuration (in application.yml file)

```
feign:
  hystrix:
    enabled: true
```